# How to capture external web site content?

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-scraping

Currently I am working on an app in this calling the external website using url. Now the Website is navigating through different pages.

I have created a button once button taped app capture the content of current url for example www.example.com/aboutme.html and want to generate pdf or png that copy all the data including every thing like data,styling images.

Note: I also used the ScreenShot cordova plugin but it is only capturing the current visible screen of the app not taking the data including scroll this is not requirement.

After google now I am using the functionality of Html2canvas
using the html2canvas.js,canvas2image.js, jspdf.debug.js

```
html2canvas( [document.body],{
         allowTait: true,
         logging:true,
         useCORS: true,
         onrendered: function(canvas) {     
         document.body.appendChild(canvas);                             
         var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0); 
         var pdf = new jsPDF();         
         pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
         pdf.save("mypdf.pdf");     
      }
    })
```

This code is working fine generating the pdf in web browser but it is not working on the device currently using Android.

2) for the device specific code please refer the below code

```
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
        html2canvas([ document.body ], {
            allowTait : true,
            logging : true,
            useCORS : true,
            onrendered : function(canvas) {
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/JPEG', 1.0);
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
            }
        });
        var pdfOutput = doc.output();
        console.log("file system...");
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(
                fileSystem) {
            console.log(fileSystem.name);
            console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
            console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
            fileSystem.root.getFile("sajjad.pdf", {
                create : true
            }, function(entry) {
                alert(entry);
                var fileEntry = entry;
                console.log("fileSystem.name" + fileSystem.name + " "
                        + "fileSystem.root.name " + fileSystem.root.name
                        + " ");
                entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                        console.log("write success");
                    };
                    console.log("writing to file");
                    writer.write(pdfOutput);
                    alert("Generating done.");
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }, function(event) {
            console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        });
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Idan thanks for editing... Currently I am using Worklight project that's why I used. we have a use case in which we are doing. Can you please help here?

Comment: Dear Idan any suggestion?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function should be able to get the html from the page but not the css and images since they are most likely external files.

Comment: Thanks Timo for your reply. Currently also following jspdf for this but still this is same issue (images & css) not rendering while contents are.